# Post-War Harry Potter becomes a porn star

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I'm looking for a fanfiction where Harry randomly decides to become a porn star because he saw an advert. He has muggle electronics in a warded room. He refuses to marry Ginny and she gives him an ultimatum so he leaves her. The group of friends hold regular parties/movie nights. Someone brings a dvd of Harry porn and Hermione recognizes his scars. Ends with Harry/ Draco.

There is almost no actual porn in this story. It's mostly just background info.

Comment: This site is only for works of fiction. Biographies of actors are better off on Movies and TV.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @Adamant I think you dropped some salt there ;-p

Comment: Why the negative votes? It seems to me to be a fair question about Drarry fanfic, which there have been dozens of already. Is it the porn angle that offends people?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - People aren't overly keen on story-ID questions about hardcore pornographic slashfic. For some reason.

Comment: @Valorum: Being uptight about pornography is no excuse for downvoting a perfectly serious question. Myself, I don't like horror at all (for some reason), but that doesn't make me downvote all horror questions. Is there anything in the guidelines forbidding questions about sf/f porn? I mean, some of that has been shortlisted for Hugo Awards and has at least on one occasion won.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - Users are allowed to like/dislike whatever they want. That you think this filth has artistic merit doesn't mean that others are obliged to.

Comment: @Valorum: Not having read that story (or any other Harry Potter fanfic) I have no idea if it has any artistic merit or is, indeed, filth. But that is neither here nor there. Whether somebody considers a story "filth" or "art" should not have any bearing on the validity of a question about it. Besides, I have never understood why depicting an act of love is "filth" while portraying the most egregious violence is quite alright. To me, that seems like a very messed-up worldview. But then, I'm a Scandinavian, not an American. Must be a culture thing.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - You seem to be mistaking downvotes (personal opinion) for close votes (must be based on policy).

Comment: @Valorum: I have always considered downvotes being about whether a question is considered poorly asked or off-topic, not about whether you dislike the subgenre asked about. I imagined that this was a serious forum, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - The tooltip says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or **not useful"***. I also take exception to the idea that not wanting the site overrun with porno makes us "not a serious forum".

Comment: @Valorum: If the tooltip says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*, why did you not use that as an argument for the downvotes rather than your personal dislike for depictions of acts of love? Furthermore, questions about written pornography will not make the site overrun with pornography, anymore than questions about gory horror will make the site overrun by gore. A question is not the thing itself. I got a notification that we move this to chat. I don't think it is worth that, but if you want, we could start an open policy debate. It is up to you.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly "[Harry Potter, Porn Star](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/6911574/1/Harry-Potter-Porn-Star)" by Reverie Wilde

> While there is plenty of smut, this is a LOVE STORY. Down and out Harry goes to work in a porn studio. And who should be there, but Draco Malfoy. Harry can't help wondering if they'll work together. post Hogwarts H/D

First page of results for me when searching for `harry potter fanfic "porn star"` mentioned this one twice.

Comment: Don't worry, we wouldn't think you know this because you watch porn :)

Comment: Thanks, @FuzzyBoots but this is not it. And just a side note, there is almost no porn in this story. It's mostly just background info.